# mysql gives response even though data does not exist

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql workbench. And the query goes like this.

```
select @uid :=`user_id` from dasa_user as var where email="ri@gmail.com" ;
select @finaluid:= `user_id` from user_type where user_id =@uid AND type="customer";
select password from customer where user_id =@finaluid;
```

here even though email `ri@gmail.com` does not exist. The query still gives the response of the password. And the password that it gives is the password of the earlier response. 
 That means if I input existed email and the query gives response of password `123`.
 Now when I enter not exist email it again gives the same output.
 What might be the reason?

Comment: You must reset variables values before use. If not then previous value will be observed. When no row with `email="ri@gmail.com"` exists then none assigning into the variable performed. And variable value stays unchanged.

Comment: Can you help me to reset the variable, do I have to use set?

Comment: Yes, you may use separate ```SET @uid := NULL;``` before. Or you may add it into the query source: ```select @uid :=`user_id` from dasa_user as var, (SELECT @uid := NULL) init_var where email="ri@gmail.com" ;```